# Hiding pygame display

Tags: python, pygame

Is there any way to hide the screen of 'pygame.display' and to make it visible afterwards without calling 'pygame.display.quit()'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627603/opengl-render-view-without-a-visible-window-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't. All you can do is minimize the window using `pygame.display.iconify()`.

Answer (score 7):

```
import os
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

would be enough. See:

http://www.pygame.org/wiki/HeadlessNoWindowsNeeded
https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment/issues/26#issuecomment-330440199

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pygame.SHOWN` and `pygame.HIDDEN` in set_mode

Hiding the display:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), flags=pygame.HIDDEN)
```

Showing the display:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), flags=pygame.SHOWN)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to actually make the screen invisible how about:

I use this:

```
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,1024), pygame.FULLSCREEN) 

        #Run my game

        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
        pygame.display.flip()

        call('I CALL AN EXTERNAL PROGRAM HERE')

        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,1024), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

to exit from fullscreen so that my second app can be seen. Its handy because it will wait for the second app to close before returning to fullscreen.