# OpenGL render view without a visible window in python

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I need to render some scene. I managed to do it in python using pyopengl and pygame. The problem is that it creates a window for a short period of time.

I want to render the same image and save it, without creating a visible window (Or possibly without creating a window at all, and even without pygame).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

def main():
    DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900
    DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 900

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT), DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(90, (DISPLAY_WIDTH / DISPLAY_HEIGHT), 0.01, 12)

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)

    glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0) # Straight rotation
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glRotatef(285, 0, 0, 1) # Rotate yaw
    glTranslatef(-5, -3, -2) # Move to position

    # Draw rectangle
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(2, 2, 0)
    glVertex3f(2, 2, 2)
    glVertex3f(2, 6, 2)
    glVertex3f(2, 6, 0)
    glEnd()

    image_buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, OpenGL.GL.GL_RGB, OpenGL.GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    image = np.frombuffer(image_buffer, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, 3)

    cv2.imwrite(r"C:\temp\image.png", image)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The only thing I know is `pygame.display.iconify()`

Comment: This indeed makes the window not to focus. But it is still created on the taskbar. I think the best solution is just to avoid pygame completely

Comment: It is not possible to create an OpenGL offscreen context with a OpenGL version above 1.0. See [Creating OpenGL context without window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482166/creating-opengl-context-without-window)

Comment: See also [Hiding pygame display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466590/hiding-pygame-display)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to render the same image and save it, without creating a visible window

It is not possible to create an [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) with an version above 1.0 without any window.
See the answer to the question [Creating OpenGL context without window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482166/creating-opengl-context-without-window).

But it is possible to use a completely hidden window for "offscreen" rendering.
Sadly it is not possible to create a initially hidden window with [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news).
It is only possible to hide a window after it was created by [`pygame.display.iconify()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.iconify).
See also [Hiding pygame display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466590/hiding-pygame-display).

But it is possible to create a initially hidden window with the [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) library by setting the [window hint](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints) `VISIBLE` to `False`.

The glfw library can be found at [glfw 1.7.0](https://pypi.org/project/glfw/).

The code may look like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import glfw

def main():
    DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900
    DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 900

    # Initialize the library
    if not glfw.init():
        return
    # Set window hint NOT visible
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, False)
    # Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfw.create_window(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, "hidden window", None, None)
    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    # Make the window's context current
    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    gluPerspective(90, (DISPLAY_WIDTH / DISPLAY_HEIGHT), 0.01, 12)

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)

    glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0) # Straight rotation
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glRotatef(285, 0, 0, 1) # Rotate yaw
    glTranslatef(-5, -3, -2) # Move to position

    # Draw rectangle
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(2, 2, 0)
    glVertex3f(2, 2, 2)
    glVertex3f(2, 6, 2)
    glVertex3f(2, 6, 0)
    glEnd()

    image_buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, OpenGL.GL.GL_RGB, OpenGL.GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    image = np.frombuffer(image_buffer, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, 3)

    cv2.imwrite(r"C:\temp\image.png", image)

    glfw.destroy_window(window)
    glfw.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with glfw3 on ubuntu, it functions as a screen recorder.